# NestJs dependency injection with task scheduling is not working as singleton

Tags: dependency-injection, scheduled-tasks, nestjs

I already checked the link [NestJs dependency injection with task scheduling is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246525/nestjs-dependency-injection-with-task-scheduling-is-not-working) but that is not the same problem that I have since I'm not using request scope on the on my injectable service.

I recorded a loom video to show the issue.
https://www.loom.com/share/37875a6e0d79400698a4408ef8d9ac89

Thanks
Tiago

Comment: Rather than adding a video, you should explain your problem in full in the question.

Comment: are you aware that providers instances are singleton _within_ the modules they were registered? So (if I've followed properly) If you want to share the same instance of `ReckonService` across modules, you'll need to register that `ReckonService` only once in `ReckonModule`, and expose it by adding it to the `exports` array.

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yep, that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks to @Micael Levi.

The problem was the provider array on AppModule. It was instantiating the ReckonService again.

Example of the ReckonModule after fix:

```
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  controllers: [ReckonController],
  providers: [ReckonService],
  exports: [ReckonService],
})
export class ReckonModule {}
```

Example of the AppModule after fix:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ReckonModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thanks
Tiago